# Consulta a través de relación ManyToMany

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

En un proyecto de Laravel y Vuejs, entre otros, tengo 2 modelos: User y Post.

Una de las relaciones que tengo establecidas entre esos dos modelos es la que considera que un usuario pueda tener uno o más posts favoritos y un post pueda ser marcada como favorito por uno o más usuarios. Esto desemboca en una tabla pivote "post_user" formada por los campos clave de cada modelo.

Y tengo estas relaciones entre los modelos:

**User.php**

```
public function post_favorites() { //Posts que fueron marcados como favoritos por el User
    return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class);
}
```

**Post.php**

```
public function post_followers() { //Usuarios que han marcado el Post como favorito
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}
```

Entonces, empleando la relación "post_followers", puedo sacar el listado de posts favoritos de un determinado usuario del que sé su ID de esta forma:

```
$user = User::withTrashed()->findOrFail($id);
return $user->post_favorites
    ->sortByDesc('title');
```

Por este lado, todo correcto a no ser que el "sortByDesc()" aplicado no me funciona (tampoco el sortBy(), ni el orderBy() aunque este último no es válido para colecciones parece ser).

Pero bueno, la cuestión del "sortByDesc" (aunque, también, me gustaría darle solución), no es la cuestión principal.

La cosa es que, aparte de sacar el listado total de posts favoritos de un usuario, también, he establecido un buscador de esos posts para poder filtrarlos por "title" de los posts resultantes. Para ello, dentro del método del controlador, he establecido este código:

```
public function profilePostsFavSearch(Request $request)
{
    $user = User::withTrashed()->findOrFail($request->user_id);
    $termino = $request->term;

    return $user->post_favorites
                ->where(function($query) use ($termino) {
                    $query->where(DB::raw('LOWER(title)'), 'LIKE', "%".strtolower($termino)."%")
                        ->orWhere(DB::raw('LOWER(slug)'), 'LIKE', "%".strtolower($termino)."%")
                        ->orWhere(DB::raw('LOWER(description)'), 'LIKE', "%".strtolower($termino)."%");
                })
                ->sortByDesc('title');
}
```

También, he probado a establecerla de esta otra forma:

```
public function profilePostsFavSearch(Request $request)
{
    $user = User::withTrashed()->findOrFail($request->user_id);
    $termino = $request->term;

    return $user->post_favorites
                ->where(function($query) use ($termino) {
                    $query->where('title', 'like', '%'.$termino.'%')
                        ->orWhere('slug', 'like', '%'.$termino.'%')
                        ->orWhere('description', 'like', '%'.$termino.'%');
                })
                ->sortByDesc('title');
}
```

Sea como sea, la petición de la búsqueda filtrada recibe este mensaje de excepción como respuesta:

```
"message": "explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given",
```

Entonces, ¿cuál es la causa del error?, ¿como puedo efectuar, correctamente, la búsqueda deseada?

---

---

[EDITADA]

Bueno, gracias a la estimable aportación del autor de la respuesta, el código resultante quedaría así entonces:

```
$user_id = $request->user_id;
$termino = $request->term;

return Post::whereHas('post_followers', function($query) use ($user_id) {
                $query->where('id', $user_id);
            })
            //===============================================================
            //Pasando a minúsculas para no considerar esa diferencia en el filtrado
            //----------------------------------------------------------
            ->where(function($query) use ($termino) {
                $query->where(DB::raw('LOWER(title)'), 'LIKE', '%'.strtolower($termino).'%')
                    ->orWhere(DB::raw('LOWER(slug)'), 'LIKE', '%'.strtolower($termino).'%')
                    ->orWhere(DB::raw('LOWER(description)'), 'LIKE', '%'.strtolower($termino).'%');
            })
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')//primero, por fecha DESC
            ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')//segundo, por ID DESC
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se puede llegar también desde User, pero si fuese yo lo haría de otra forma. 
Si lo que quiero obtener son los Posts, lo que quiero filtrar son los Posts y lo que quiero ordenar son los Posts, la consulta la haría sobre el modelo Post y no sobre el modelo User. Además lo haría todo en la consulta a BD y no sobre la colección.

Entonces haría una consulta como esta:

```
$termino = $request->term;
$user_id = $request->user_id;
return Post::whereHas('post_followers', function($query) use ($user_id) {
                $query->where("id", $user_id);
            })
            ->where('title', 'like', '%'.$termino.'%')
            ->orWhere('slug', 'like', '%'.$termino.'%')
            ->orWhere('description', 'like', '%'.$termino.'%');
            ->orderBy('title', 'desc')
            ->get();
```

Comment: Gracias compañero por tu estimable respuesta. Lo que más me ha gustado es el planteamiento lógico. Es algo que trato de seguir ... la lógica. Aunque, a veces, uno se desvía. No obstante, en este caso, el sortBy debe ser sustituido por orderBy pues el sortBy es para colecciones. Por otro lado, entonces, ¿me podrías decir para que casos se emplearía el hacer una consulta del tipo que pretendía a través de una relación? Es decir, ¿para qué casos sería útil algo como `return $user->post_favorites`?

Comment: Oh! es cierto, se me pasó eso, ahí lo edité. Gracias por el aviso! Respondiendo a lo que preguntas, para este caso, supongo que lo usaría para devolver la información del usuario incluyendo sus posts favoritos `return $user` directamente. Creo que eso depende más de la [lógica de negocio](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B3gica_de_negocio), y por parte de la programación uno trata de hacer un sistema eficiente y escalable.  Da para una charla más que para un comentario, pero por ahí va la idea.